# Pig-0.10.0: CSVLoader cannot be cast to org.apache.pig.StoreFuncInterface

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong with this. The script works perfectly well for PigStorage but gives me this ClassCastException for CSVLoader.

I checked the documentation and it didn't help.

Here is the Stack Trace:

```
Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 1200: Pig script failed to parse: 
<file pig_script.pig, line 15, column 0> pig script failed to validate: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVLoader cannot be cast to org.apache.pig.StoreFuncInterface
org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Pig script failed to parse: 
<file pig_script.pig, line 15, column 0> pig script failed to validate: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVLoader cannot be cast to org.apache.pig.StoreFuncInterface
at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.parseQuery(PigServer.java:1597)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.registerQuery(PigServer.java:1540)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerQuery(PigServer.java:540)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processPig(GruntParser.java:970)
at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:386)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:189)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:165)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:84)
at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:555)
at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:111)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without your pig script, this is a guess, but are you trying to use CSVLoader in a STORE statement?

[CSVLoader](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.2/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/CSVLoader.html) doesn't implement the [StoreFuncInterface](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.2/api/org/apache/pig/StoreFuncInterface.html), which is required for anything you want to use to store your results to. CSVLoader is used in LOAD statements.

You probably want [CSVExcelStorage](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.2/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/CSVExcelStorage.html) instead as this does implement the interface. The previous link details usage too:

```
STORE x INTO '<destFileName>'
USING CSVExcelStorage(['<delimiter>' [,{'YES_MULTILINE' | 'NO_MULTILINE'} [,{'UNIX' | 'WINDOWS' | 'UNCHANGED'}]]]);
```